# How to make it more Pythonic?

Tags: python, path

I'm learning Python. I found [this](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=635101#s=p0) problem from Google Code Jam. And solved it by writing this code. It works correctly But What are the other possibilities to make this code more Pythonic, Increase Speed or in anyway better. Thanks.

```
import sys

def split_path(f,c):
    result_list = []
    for i in range(c):
        l = f.readline()
        l = l[1:]
        l = l.strip()
        splited = l.split('/')
        for j in range(1,len(splited)+1):
            joined = "/".join(splited[:j])
            result_list.append(joined)
    return result_list

def main():

    file_name = sys.argv[1]

    if not file_name:
        file_name = "A-small-practice.in"

    f = open(file_name)

    l = f.readline()
    #t = int(l)

    case_no = 0

    while True:
        l = f.readline()

        if not l:
            break

        e,n = l.split()
        e = int(e)
        n = int(n)      

        e_list = split_path(f,e)

        n_list = split_path(f,n)

        new_set = set(n_list) - set(e_list)     

        case_no += 1

        print "Case #%d: %d" % (case_no,len(new_set))

    f.close()   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Which do you want: more Pythonic, faster or better? What's wrong with it at the moment?

Comment: This seems like a fairly open-ended question.

Comment: You may get better answers if you try asking here: [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @David,@Justin as @Gabe said this is more of a open-ended question.

Comment: @John Thanks I didn't know CodeReview.SE exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys

def getInts(s):
    "Convert string to list of integers"
    return [int(i) for i in s.strip().split()]

def getPath(s, sep='/'):
    "Convert string to list of directory names"
    dirs = s.strip().split(sep)
    dirs.pop(0)  # remove empty root-dir string
    return dirs

def addPath(tree, path):
    "Recursively add a path to dir tree, return number of dirs added"
    if path:
        this = path.pop(0)
        if this in tree:
            added = 0
        else:
            tree[this] = {}
            added = 1
        return added + addPath(tree[this], path)
    else:
        return 0

def doTest(f):
    "Run one test cycle"
    old,new = getInts(f.next())
    root = {}
    oldDirs = sum(addPath(root, getPath(f.next())) for i in range(old))
    newDirs = sum(addPath(root, getPath(f.next())) for i in range(new))
    return newDirs

def main():
    try:
        fileName = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        fileName = "A-small-practice.in"

    with open(fileName) as f:
        numTests, = getInts(f.next())
        for test in range(numTests):
            print("Case #{0}: {1}".format(test+1, doTest(f)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comments:

- meaningful function names, variable names, and docstrings help you figure out what's going on.
- a functional programming style is good - short single-purpose 'building-block' functions without side effects which can be easily combined and reused.
- `split_path` is not a good function name; looking at it, it should be called something like allSubpaths and should return a set (have all duplicates pre-removed).
- testing is good; your code

  ```
  file_name = sys.argv[1]
  if not file_name:
      file_name = "A-small-practice.in"
  ```

  will throw an exception if it does not receive a command-line argument; `if not file_name` will never be reached.

Comment: Sorry, This is more like open-ended question so i cant choose one reply as answer. But I learned more from your code :)

Comment: of course you can choose an answer!!

Answer (score 1):

For example:

Use `with` to make it more Pythonic:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    data = f.readline()
    #do something with data
```

Now you don't have to close anything. Python does it for you.

Comment: +1.  But this sort of code isn't unique to Python.  C++ has RAII and C# has `using`.  Using "Pythonic" to describe code like this is a pretty poor use of language, IMO.  No downvote, since your answer is still a good suggestion - this is more a comment on the question :)

Comment: i won't call `with` "pythonic" but "pedantic" (still starts with P). even if you don't use `with` as in `all_data = open('somefile').read()`, python will take care to close the file when variable is disposed - which in our case is right after the assignment. `with` just makes sure cleanup will be done no matter how we exit the block; nothing "pythonic" about it

Answer (score 1):

Too open a question, but subjective as it is, I'd say:

- Don't reuse the same variable to store different values (i.e. `l`). Also, don't use l (because it's hard to tell from number one). Use meaningful names: `line`.
- Use a generator for `split_path`.
- Don't insert blank lines with no reason.

Comment: There are extra newlines in some places.  Adding whitespace immediately around control flow structures is widely included in coding standards, so those parts are fine.

Comment: @Merlyn, I certaintly agree that blank spaces serve a visual hint to separate logic blocks, but did you looked at main()? it's almost completely double-space for now apparent reason.

Comment: Absolutely.  Just wanted to clarify "blank lines with no reason".

Comment: Thanks and I will look more into generator for split_path.